# FireFox ADMX Extension Management via GPO not working

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, gpo

Trying to block all but allow specific plugins. I have the okta one and the web password filler working, but not the logon assist. I've tried putting in (secret-server-logon-assist-ff57@thycotic.com), and {secret-server-logon-assist-ff57@thycotic.com}, and also without any extras. These codes come from just the numeric URL (ie https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/file/1747490) which says "Secret Server Login Assist (secret-server-logon-assist-ff57@thycotic.com) is blocked by your system administrator. Extension not on OAI allowed list". Am I misreading this message, or missing something on this specific one?

I posted this on [support.mozilla.org](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1370283), but haven't gotten any replies yet...

```
{
"*": {
"blocked_install_message" : "Extension not on OAI allowed list",
"installation_mode": "blocked"
},
"dd1e31d5-3623-45cb-b1ad-64074d36b360@thycotic.com": {
"installation_mode": "allowed",
"install_url": "https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/file/3906662/secret_server_web_password_filler-3.2-fx.xpi"
},
"secret-server-logon-assist-ff57@thycotic.com": {
"installation_mode": "allowed",
"install_url": "https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/file/1747490/secret_server_login_assist-2.1.1-an+fx.xpi"
},
"plugin@okta.com": {
"installation_mode": "allowed",
"install_url": "https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/file/3901586/okta_browser_plugin-6.8.0-an+fx.xpi"
}
}
```

[snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nU7r.png)